# How to create a type with values from plain object?

Tags: typescript

I had a object like this:

```
const myObject = {
  0: 'FIRST',
  10: 'SECOND',
  20: 'THIRD',
}
```

I want to create a type with this object values, like this:

```
type AwesomeType = 'FIRST' | 'SECOND' | 'THIRD';
```

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the variable (object) type you can use [`typeof` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html#the-typeof-type-operator). To prevent literal types widening you can use [`as const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const myObject = {
  0: 'FIRST',
  10: 'SECOND',
  20: 'THIRD',
} as const;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T];

type AwesomeType = Values<typeof myObject>; // "FIRST" | "SECOND" | "THIRD"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDAAwBcMA5AGICSASgMoAqVANMTAIwXVMBRAMJIAcgBEOXAEx8qLABKNJnAL4wAhhBihIUANyFCUBAAcMMAGoaANgFcMEADwsAfDDwsA2gGsMCEAAzGBYAXUNjMwsAQQB3RxA4DBYojytbB2cTcyD4ZHQsKFd9GAB6UpgAInpmFkqYAB8qwREJeqbKxWVKoA)

Comment: Awesome. ```as const``` solves the question. I've struggling to understand why typescript was returning only the value type and not the string const instead. Thanks man!

Comment: AwesomeType is equivalent to `Record<string,string>` in this case. I think he wants AwesomeType to be `Record<string, "FIRST" | "SECOND" | "THIRD">`. I added example in your code. [Playgroud](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDAAwBcMA5AGICSASgMoAqVANMTAIwXVMBRAMJIAcgBEOXAEx8qLABKNJnAL4wAhhBihIUANyFCuiCAA2GAHRmQAcwAUUBAAcMIAGbxk6LFACUhk6uMABqGmYArhgQADwsAHwweCwA2gDWGAgeMCwAuoaEQRgwAIIA7tEgcBgsLsV4YZHRMUXZiKiY2PH6MAD0vTAARPTMLIMwAD5DgiIS41ODisqDRiawiJTlldW1wXhEJBow5LSMrFIkKMdUM2IqXMDXSwyShKpAA)

Comment: @SubatoPatnaik, no the desired type is `type AwesomeType = 'FIRST' | 'SECOND' | 'THIRD'`. Type which represents all possible object values, not the object itself

Comment: @AlekseyL. Could you give an example with the playground?  Btw I like your answer.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwPICMBWBTYsC8MDeAUDDAAwBcMA5AGICSASgMoAqVANMTAIwXVMBRAMJIAcgBEOXAEx8qLABKNJnAL4wAhhBihIUANyFCuiCAA2GAHRmQAcwAUUBAAcMIAGbxk6LFACUhk6uMABqGmYArhgQADwsAHwweCwA2gDWGAgeMCwAuoaEQRgwAIIA7tEgcBgsLsV4YZHRMUXZiKiY2PH6MAD0vTAARPTMLIMwAD5DgiIS41ODisqDRiaw7iAglOWV1bXBeLSMrFQF-TACAB6u2BgAJjAYAE5PIE+U+8VUg1DRUINUGAAS20YBAsC0ECBtjAGhQFhgUBAiLq1B2pj2dSoxnA0BgKA071KFQxNVRh1+0FOQA

Answer (score 2):

Do it this way

```
type AwesomeType = 'FIRST' | 'SECOND' | 'THIRD';
type MyType = Record<number, AwesomeType>

const myObject: MyType = {
  0: 'FIRST',
  10: 'SECOND',
  20: 'THIRD',
}
```

see in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggdygZwPYFsoBVKwLwwDkAYgJIBKAyloTAD5GUCiAwgPIByAIrQ4VgAkKPANyhcMALJgc0GAXJQAxqgBOAEwA8AOwCu6AEZRVAGnhI0mWVAB8wYCu3IQMdGDYGAVspAAuKTISBADewDAwAAz+JBTUhCZhMACMUYysnDwJ4QBMqfxC5JnAAL72QA)